# Error "Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'." trying to insert row int a table with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been stuck on this error for an hour and I desperately need other's help now. I don't know how to find the error, so I'll just show what I've coded here.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddProduct @id nvarchar(100), @name nvarchar(100), @price money, 
                         @type int
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO Product (product_id, product_name, product_price, [type_id])
                VALUES(@id, @name, @price, @type);
        COMMIT;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK;
        END CATCH
    END;
GO
```

And here's in my C# Function

```
public void Add()
    {
        string command = "EXEC AddProduct @id nvarchar(100), @name nvarchar(100), @price money, @type int";
        var query = Connection.InitSqlCommand(command);
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price);
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Type);
        Connection.ExecuteQuery(query);    
    }
```

Edit:
Here's what's in my other class

```
public void ExecuteQuery(SqlCommand command)
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
public SqlCommand InitSqlCommand(string query)
    {
        var Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        return Sqlcommand;
    }
```

Here's what my whole DatabaseConnection look like now:

```
public SqlCommand InitSqlCommand(string query, CommandType commandType)
    {
        var Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        Sqlcommand.CommandType = commandType;
        return Sqlcommand;
    }
    public DataTable GetData(SqlCommand command)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = command };
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
    public void ExecuteQuery(SqlCommand command)
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    public bool ReadSqlCommand(SqlCommand command)
    {
        con.Open();
        var activateCommand = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (activateCommand.Read())
        {
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool ReadStringQuery(string command)
    {
        con.Open();
        var activateCommand = InitSqlCommand(command, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ExecuteReader();

        if (activateCommand.Read())
        {
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: I see potential problems especially in how you are using SqlConnection, a shared instance is usually not recommended because it will never be thread safe and you gain no performance in using it anyway. Please refer to [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements).

Answer (score 2):

When you call stored procedure you don't need to specify the datatypes with parameter and actually don't even need to add parameters with `exec` command as you are adding parameters down in `Parameters` collection, that is what you are doing wrong change it to be :

```
string command = "AddProduct";
```

and specify `CommandType` of `SqlCommand` object as well, better would be to make it parameter and give caller option to specify `CommandType`:

```
public SqlCommand InitSqlCommand(string query,CommandType commandType)
{
    var Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    Sqlcommand.CommandType = commandType;
    return Sqlcommand;
}
```

and call it like:

```
string command = "AddProduct";
var query = Connection.InitSqlCommand(command,CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: Changed it to what you told me but now I'm getting this new error "Procedure or function 'AddProduct' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied."

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() it's now in my question description

Comment: you havent specified ``CommandType`` of your ``Sqlcommand``, it can be ``Text`` or ``StoredProcedure``, in your case it should be StroedProcedure